# Creating a reverse proxy

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

How do you create a reverse proxy? I want to create a site that uses a table of urls with identifiers for each url. If you go to http://site.com/id where id is an identifier for a url it would act as a reverse proxy and retrieve the content from the url.

I looked into using apache reverse proxy features but there doesn't seem to be a way to scale it without restarting the server every time you need to reverse proxy a new site.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for not wanting to restart your proxy server when you add a rule?

Comment: I plan on their being a lot of new rules being added on the fly so restarting the server every time doesn't seem practical.

Answer (score 1):

Using Apache to create a reverse proxy using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in the main `httpd.conf` (under the relevant  if applicable):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/id$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.proxydomain.com/newUrl [P,L]
```

First line checks for `www.mydomain.com` or `mydomain.com`

Second line identifies the `/id` portion of the URL

If the first two conditions are met the request is made by Apache to `www.proxydomain.com/newUrl` and then returned to the client.

You don't have to fully restart Apache to make these changes. Do a config check and then restart gracefully, which doesn't take the server offline and reloads configuration:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd configtest && /etc/init.d/httpd graceful
```

Alternatively this code can go into an `.htaccess` file, which is [less preferable](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when).

Comment: @sarnold yes, but it will still shut the server down, so if you have an error you can't start it again until you've fixed your config - chaining commands prevents this http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/stopping.html#graceful

Comment: @Andy, interesting, that directly contradicts `apachectl(8)` manpage :) `This command automatically checks the configuration files via apache2ctl configtest before initiating the restart to to catch the most obvious errors. However, it is still possible for the daemon to die because of problems with the configuration.` I wonder which is correct? :)

Comment: (Hah, `to to catch the most obvious errors`, pity there's no similar tool for manpage authors. :)

Comment: @sarnold I suspect this behaviour has changed over the years as I've been bitten before, however cursory testing on 2.2 gives `apachectl: Configuration syntax error, will not run "graceful"`

Comment: But this assumes that I always plan on redirecting to some page on  http://www.proxydomain.com. I plan on redirecting to many different pages.